# Is Django 1.2.3 competable with Python 2.6.5

Tags: python, django

Just curious to know, Test module won't work properly with django 1.2.3 when update from django 1.1.1 (now on python 2.6.5)

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'Test module won't work properly'? A traceback or at least the exception name would help us to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You're having other problems.